# Meeting young people in Mongolia, especially outside UB

Tags: culture, mongolia, socializing

Compared to [Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18126/where-can-i-socialize-with-young-japanese-people), I know that Mongolia has a lower population density, but also a lower average age.

Will I have any difficulty meeting young people of both genders? In particular, are people in their twenties and thirties still in the countryside, or have they all migrated to UB?

(I've already heard that bars and nightclubs aren't particularly safe for single, foreign males, BTW)

Comment: There's little to *do* anywhere outside UB, except enjoy the countryside. So, also few occasions to meet anyone. And, unless you speak Mongolian, it's going to be hard. But, if you do, striking up a conversation with anyone, anywhere, will be enjoyed by pretty much everyone.

Comment: You can try the Tripr app on your phone which may help you meet other travellers. It gives you an idea how many people are in the area or visiting before you go there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I lived in UB for a year and have visited on and off for the last 10 years. Its VERY easy to meet people in Mongolia. But please note about 50% of the population now lives in UB. That said, in the summer time (very short period!) everyone likes to spend time in the country side. So there is much enjoying, relaxing etc.

In my experience traveling around Mongolia, somehow, no matter how remote, there was always a horseman (maybe now a motorcycleman!) around to find out about you - what you were doing there, where you were from etc. There were children and older people in the countryside. And yes..language was an issue...many people could speak Russian then, now I don't know. So go and visit. Every Ger will welcome you. Bring something as a small gift to leave.